# How do I set permissions on a Server 2003 folder

Tags: windows-server-2003, permissions

In my part time position as entire IT department at my Office ( I'm a MCSD developer normally ) I have been asked to change a shared folder.

Only I don't really understand all the Shared / Security options.

I have a folder that must be accessed by 2 people in the company (and no one else).
They both must have read/write/edit and change access.

They must be able to read/write/edit each others files; existing or newly created.

Should be easy but I'm a bit overwhelemd by all the choices.

What should I set?

Thanks for your help
richard

Answer (score 2):

There are two aspects to address: the share permissions, and the NTFS permissions. You need to provide the applicable users/group permissions in both.

Right-click the folder/s in question, properties, in the sharing tab "share this folder". Then:

1. Permissions: add user/group and give change/read.
2. Then go to security tab and add group or user and check Modify permissions. That will select all necessary sub-permissions.

OK your way out and you're done.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Has a bit of a struggle with the inherited permissions but your advice essentially did it.